# show the selected value in the dropdown in jsp(bootstrap dropdown)

Tags: java, jsp, drop-down-menu

I have a JSP page say, xyz.jsp. It has a drop-down menu(Bootstrap dropdown) that lists financial years. And I am passing the selected option to the URL query string. Also I want the selected option to be displayed as the title of the dropdown button.

I am either able to pass the query string or display the selected option on the dropdown button both are not happening simultaneously.

```
<div id="yeardropdown" class="dropdown" style="margin-top: -60px; float: right; border-radius: 8px;">
  <button class="dropbtn" style ="text-align:center;"><span id="selected">Year</span><span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-content">
  <% for (String uniqueFinancialYear :uniqueValues) {%>
   <li> <a><%= uniqueFinancialYear %></a></li>
    <%} %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This is my code for sending the selected option to query string and its succesfully working:

```
  $('.dropdown-content a').on('click', function() {
window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?year=" + this["innerHTML"];
    });
```

This is the code i have tried for displaying the selected option as title of dropdown button:

```
$('.dropdown-content a').click(function(){
    $('#selected').text($(this).text());
 });
```

I want to pass the selected dropdown option to query string and also display the selected option on the dropdown button.

Comment: What do you mean with title of dropdown?

Comment: `$('#selected').text( $(this).find(':selected').text());`

Comment: The button displays "Year" on page load ,after i select an option from the dropdown list ,that option should be displayed in place of "Year".